# shuffle : Display only one row at the same time

Tags: php, random, shuffle

How to display only one row at random at the same time from DB. Everything works fine, but all rows are displayed. thanks

```
<?php                             
 $sql = "SELECT id,name  FROM table ";
 $rows = array();
 $result = $objCon->query($sql);    
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   {                      
   $rows[] = $row;
   }                                     
 shuffle($rows);  
 echo '<ol>';
 foreach($rows as $row)
   {
   echo '<li><h3>'.$row['id'].' = '.$row['name'].'</h3></li>';
   }

 echo '</ol>';                         

?>
```

Comment: The shuffle only shuffles. You are still looping through all rows returned from database.. just not in the same order. why doing foreach loop if you need only one?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";` if your using mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using PHP:

```
....
shuffle($rows);  
$randomRow = reset($rows);

....
```

But the better way is to change your SQL query:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;"
```

Comment: @letris you are welcome, you could mark my vote up and mark my answer resolving. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL request:

SELECT id,name FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $sql = "
    SELECT id, name  
    FROM table
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1 ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 

    // As you are only return a single row you do you require the while()   
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo '<ol>';
      echo '<li><h3>'.$row['id'].' = '.$row['name'].'</h3></li>';
    echo '</ol>';
?>
```

By adding an ORDER BY RAND() in your sql query you are asking MySQL to randomly order the results then at a LIMIT to restrict the number of rows you would like returned.

The example code is written based on selecting a single row.  If you would like more, e.g. 5, you will need to add a while loop.